# How to execute a function inside listen switch only one time

Tags: flutter, showdialog

I have a function inside a switch that is inside a listen and I want that function to be executed only one time ( it's an Alert Dialog that I want to be shown case the return is true ( it's the function fun234(); inside the case StatusRequisicao.REQUISICAO. The problem is that when i execute the code, the Dialog is shown multiple times

```
_adicionarListenerRequisicao({String? idUsuario, String? nome,String? About, String? mood, String? Interests, String? likes, String? urlImagemRecuperadaBackground, String? urlImagem, String? idDestinatario, String? Destinatario, String? Remetente,String? idRequisicao})async{
    FirebaseAuth auth2 = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot4 = await db.collection("requisicao_ativa").where("id_destinatario", isEqualTo: auth2.currentUser!.uid).get();
    setState((){
      allData = querySnapshot4.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
    });
    String idRequisicao = _dadosRequisicao!["id"] == null ? ' ' : _dadosRequisicao!["id"];
    await db.collection("requisicoes")
        .doc(idRequisicao)
        .snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.data() != null){
        Map<String, dynamic> dados = snapshot.data() as Map<String,dynamic>;
        String status = dados["status"];
        switch (status){
          case StatusRequisicao.AGUARDANDO:

            break;
          case StatusRequisicao.REQUISICAO:
            fun234(idUsuario: idDestinatario,idRequisicao: idRequisicao,nome: nome, About: About, mood: mood, Interests: Interests, likes: likes, urlImagemRecuperadaBackground: urlImagemRecuperadaBackground, urlImagem: urlImagem, idDestinatario: idDestinatario);
            break;
          case StatusRequisicao.CONVERSANDO:

            break;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using [take method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/take.html) of Stream

```
    Stream.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      (i) => i,
    ).take(1).listen((event) {/* do something once */});
```

Comment: I've tried this but the dialog is still appearing a lot of times

Comment: @WagnerTiburcio please share your code